# Eclipse c/c++ "Program file does not exist"

Tags: c++, eclipse

I've been trying to solve this problem with eclipse when trying to run a c++ project. I don't exactly know why it started saying that the program file does not exist because the exact same project was working fine before. All I did was add some more code and ever since, I could not build this project, I already tried changing the launch configuration in the project properties but it didn't really do anything. Has anyone encountered this problem, and if you did is there any way to solve it?

[image: Eclipse Screenshot]

...Also it says that the "Program 'g++' was not found in path", which I don't even know why it's even looking for it in that path since I specified where the ***mingw64 HOME*** was, but if I create a new project or run an old project it builds and runs fine without any problems...

Comment: Please fix code snippet indentation issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ref this Link
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1068098/

Go to Properties for your project, select Run/Debug Setttings, select "Edit",
Notice text box C/C++ application is empty, fill it by selecting "Search Project" in your debug directory for your .exe file

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks, i had this problem. But why cant it find the .exe on its own, it did build it?

Comment: This helps me. My improvement for Ubuntu ${project_loc}/Debug/${project_name}

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to choose the .elf in the binaries section

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).